# dispatch_source_create don't work for deployment target iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode5, sftp

Below code works perfectly for deployment target set to below iOS 6. But if i change to 6.0 then it returns "OS_dispatch_source" instead of "dispatch_source_t". So it crashes whenever try to use "timeoutTimer". Please help.

```
    dispatch_source_t timeoutTimer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,
                                                         dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0));
```